# Can I use ng-click and onclick together

Tags: angularjs, onclick, angularjs-ng-click

I am working on one small angularjs app. I have a button, where I am using 2 events, ng-click, and onlick. It works right and there are no issues, but I want to be sure 100% I am doing it good and is my approach right ?
Is it allowed to have them together at a button state events ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 12):

You can bind as many events as you wish to a button etc. But this is superfluous. See this [jsFiddle: Bind events](http://jsfiddle.net/3nkoLjdq/)

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ngFn = function () {
        console.log("ngFn is triggered!");
    };
}

function nativeFn() {
    console.log("nativeFn is triggered!");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#forJq').bind('click', function () {
        console.log("Anonymous function bind by jq is triggered!");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button id="forJq" onclick="nativeFn()" ng-click="ngFn()">Try me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single btn, it's ok to use `ng-click` or `onclick` in the `ng-app`. There is no difference between the two functions. For effective team work, you,d better to have an account with each other. In Angular apps, `ng-click` is recommended.

Comment: you can have a try, but it's not necessary that you take them together